# Hadoop development - Dedicated user in Ubuntu. How to access Hadoop node running on dedicated user in Ubuntu from another user account?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, hadoop, apache-kafka

I have setup up a single node Hadoop cluster + Kafka on my Ubuntu machine. I have a dedicated user "hduser" in Ubuntu which has the installation. But, my eclipse IDE and workspace is in another user "devuser".

Is it possible for my hadoop namednode and datanode to be functioning in "hduser" and I am able to do my development in "devuser" ?

Appreciate your inputs here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a stab at answering this since no one else has, but I'm far from an authority on the topic. I might suggest a group-based-permissions approach. Creating user *groups* to which you can tie the required permissions (execution, ownership, etc.), then you can add your own user to the necessary groups to enable that user's access to the various directories/files. Say, for example, you make a group `hadoopusers`, which has privileges to hadoop executable(s), and a group `developers` which has read/write access to the Eclipse workspace. Then add your user to those groups and you could run both from a single login.

Like I said, though, I'm rather an amateur on matters of security, servers, and the like -- I mostly tinker and break my own at home, nothing at-risk in a production environment. In fact, I only found your post because I was looking for an answer to the question of *why* a dedicated user is good practice. Everything I find just says "to keep things separate on the same machine", but I'm looking for the "why" behind that.

[Basic Ubuntu documentation on user/group management](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/user-management.html) 
[Forum post with basic user/group commands](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1583028&s=76a856e5d21bf05b1d93e70558676115&p=9906389#post9906389)